# How can I convert a type to a new one based on it?

Tags: go

I create a new type to add custom methods specific for my app's needs

```
type Content html.Node
```

I know I can derivate a html.Node from a `content` var of type `Content` doing this

```
node := html.Node(content)
```

But, having a var of type `html.Node`, how can I convert to a `Content` ?

I discovered that doing the following ...

```
ndoe, err := htmlquery.LoadURL(page.url)

content := Content(node)
```

... cannot work. It gives me this error:

> cannot convert doc (variable of type *html.Node) to type Content

Comment: What do you mean it cannot work? https://go.dev/play/p/YCaywpJ8pYK

Comment: That is how you convert it. What happens when you do it?

Comment: Added error I receive

Comment: If `node` is `*html.Node` you need to convert to `*Content` not `Content`, e.g.: `(*Content)(node)`

Comment: @mkopriva This is exactly what I want to do. I don't need no methods from original type

Comment: @mkopriva : how can I convert node to Content instead of *Content ?

Comment: @realtebo dereference the pointer first, e.g. `Content(*node)`, or dereference the pointer _after_, e.g. `*(*Content)(node)`.

Comment: Please, someone add a formal answer with the 2 possibilities !

Comment: Note that if a type defines itself with pointer receivers, and pointers are returned from functions creating that value, you probably always want to maintain that value as a pointer. It may work for your purpose here, but copying values which are not meant to be copied can lead to trouble later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions

If node is `html.Node` use:

```golang
c := Content(node)
```

---

If node is `*html.Node` use:

```golang
c := (*Content)(node)
```

Note from the above linked spec: *"If the type starts with the operator `*` ... it must be parenthesized when necessary to avoid ambiguity."*

---

And if you want `Content` instead of `*Content` then you need to dereference the pointer, either before conversion or after, e.g.:

```golang
c := Content(*node) // dereference before conversion
// or
c := *(*Content)(node) // dereference after conversion
```

https://go.dev/play/p/zAu4H1R2D-L